# Undefined value set by previous Jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxform

I am trying to post a form with dynamic set value on click event by getting undefined respose Here is my code.

```
$( ".paymentselect" ).click(function() {
    var bookingid=$(this).data('id');
    $('#paymentstats').css('display','block');
    $('#paymentform').attr('action', document.location.origin +"/accounts/" + bookingid);

});

$('#paymentform').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var data=$('#paymentform').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                            // setting a timeout
                        $('#wait').html('<i class="material-icons">cached</i>');
                        },
            success: function(data){
                        if(data.status){
                            $('#paymentstats').css('display','none');
                            alert("UPDATED");
                            //location.reload();
                        }else
                        {
                            alert("something went wrong");
                        }
                        }
        });
});
```

On POST **bookingid** is Undefind. **Little Help will be appriciated**

**EDITED :**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button class="paymentselect" data-id="NH7003687415654"> Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<table>

<div id="paymentstats" class="custom-modal">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="card" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <form id="paymentform" method="POST"> //form that will be posted
                    <div class="body">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="utr" name="utr" placeholder="" required>
                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="bookingpaymentid" name="id" placeholder="">
                                </div>
                                <label class="small-label" for="utr">Payment UTR(if any)</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ref" name="ref" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                                <label class="small-label" for="ref">Payment Ref</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="spin" id="wait"></div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised bg-pink waves-effect">Submit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-raised bg-red waves-effect" id="close-btn">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form> 
        </div>

</div>
```

As requested Above is my html Code As requested.
I ALREADY TRIED SETTING **bookingpaymentid Val** on click event But It Also shows Undefined when Form is POST On the Server.

**I just figured out that value become undefined when i post form . Any Suggestion**

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: What is the value of .paymentselect data attribute id, can you elaborate?

Comment: Would you please share your html form.

Comment: I shared the html can you suggest something..

Answer (score 1):

Because you declare `bookingid` inside `$( ".paymentselect" ).click(function() {`.
You can try this:

```
var bookingid = null;
$( ".paymentselect" ).click(function() {
    bookingid=$(this).data('id');
    $('#paymentstats').css('display','block');
    $('#paymentform').attr('action', document.location.origin +"/accounts/" + bookingid);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Yhose Widtantio But i already did this but nothing is working thats why i post it here .

Comment: Why you not add hidden text inside <form id="paymentform" method="POST">, then when you click paymentselect, you set value of hidden click with value of $(this).data('id').

Comment: You can see above their is an hidden input type . already tried during this but nothing helped me.Its still undefined when i post it

Comment: if input hidden you mean id="bookingpaymentid" name="id" .
you never set value of id="bookingpaymentid", you can set inside $( ".paymentselect" ).click(function() {

Comment: the above code that i post is alternative to the previous one which is the one you are suggesting now. action attr is set on click event but it is still undefined. this is the same problem when i set hidden input value.

Answer (score 0):

In plunker `bookingid` is not undefined. Go to plunker [address](https://plnkr.co/edit/EU3gjxH6vo68sSI59ZOP?p=preview) and check browser console to see variable's values.

You might be having trouble to load order of your `scripts` file. As you can see in plunker make sure to load your `js` codes end of the `body` tag.